# Printing out bool options with cout

Tags: c++

I know that in case your bool function only prints out some text, there are two ways of printing out the outcome. One is pretty straightforward, like so:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

bool function(int x) 
{ 
   int y=5; 
   return x==y; 
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
   int a; 
   cin >> a; 
   if(function(a))
      cout << "Equal to 5"; 
   else
      cout << "Not equal to 5"; 
 }
```

I used to know other way to print out some 'messages' within one line using cout and bool in the same line, but the following solution doesn't do the trick. What is wrong with that ?

```
 cout << function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal";
```

I get the notification that function called function will always return  true, which is quite weird.

Comment: operator precedence... `cout << (function(a) ? "equal" : "not equal");` Also, **turn on compiler warnings.**

Comment: Operator precedence.

Comment: @TheParam There're on. He paraphrased one of them.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with bool and even less to do with printing, but I'll let you off.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was thinking about purging the `boolean` tag... it really is irrelevant.

Comment: Useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

Comment: Due to the precedence everyone is mentioning, your statement is being compiled with equivalency to  `(cout << function(a)) ? "Equal : "Not Equal";` (since no one bothered to explain **why** said-precedence was causing your issue).

Comment: @TheParam And entirely useless on any question

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your compiler, it may give a warning that tells exactly what the problem is.

```
main.cpp:15:21: warning: operator '?:' has lower precedence than '<<'; '<<' will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
cout << function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal"; 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
main.cpp:15:21: note: place parentheses around the '<<' expression to silence this warning
cout << function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal"; 
                    ^
(                  )
main.cpp:15:21: note: place parentheses around the '?:' expression to evaluate it first
cout << function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal"; 
main.cpp:15:26: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
   cout << function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal";
```

As [@The Paramagnetic Croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596509/printing-out-bool-options-with-cout#comment41807427_26596509) says, surround it in parentheses.

```
cout << (function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal");
```

Per [@WhozCraig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596509/printing-out-bool-options-with-cout/26596578#comment41807654_26596509), an explanation is order. As the warning says, `<<` is evaluated first, resulting in `(cout << function(a)) ? "Equal : "Not Equal";`. This returns "Equal" (or "Not Equal", it's immaterial), resulting in the subsequent "expression result unused" warning.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this you what you meant or even need but have you considered using `std::boolalpha`?

```
std::cout << function(5) << ' ' << function(6) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::function(5) << ' ' << function(6) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1 0
true false
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cout << (function(a) ? "Equal" : "Not equal");
```