# Why are parenthesis needed for this conditional expression

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements

```
var notice = "She is" + present ? "" : "n't" + " here.";
```

versus

```
var notice = "She is" + (present ? "" : "n't") + " here.";
```

After fiddling around, I notice that it's only the string before the

```
present ? "" : "n't"
```

that's messing with it. But I have no explanation as to why, if I were to alert notice (and of course have present be truthy or falsey), that it comes up blank with the first example, and works fine with the second.

Comment: [*Operator precedence*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) might be a clue.

Comment: C'mon people, really, [nobody groks this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596509/printing-out-bool-options-with-cout#comment41807427_26596509)?

Comment: If that's the case. then wouldn't it be coming back as truth anyway, since Sheis+present, which let's say we set to 1, would be She is1, ohhhhh. so then I assume that comes up as nothing. but what about the  + " here. ?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Referring to RobG's link about precedence when you leave out the parenthesis you effectively get ("She is" + present) ? "" : ("n't" + " here."). No matter what present is this evaluates to if (true) then "" else "n't here". So no matter what you have for present you get "". And don't feel bad I had to scratch my head on this and I spend allot of time in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
var notice = "She is" + present ? "" : "n't"  + " here.";
```

the [*addition operator*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) `+` [*takes precedence*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) so the parser treats it as:

```
var notice = ("She is" + present) ? "" : ("n't"  + " here.");
```

The expression `"She is" + present` returns true regardless of the value of *present* since it is converted to a string in the expression (and [*ToBoolean*](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) applied to any non–empty string returns true), so the full expression returns `""`, i.e. the true side of the conditional operation.

When the grouping operator is applied to the conditional part, it takes precedence over everything so the conditional is evaluated first:

```
var notice = "She is" + (present ? "" : "n't")  + " here.";
```